# R object seems to randomly exist

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

[image]

When I create an object, here its a data.table, in R-Studio, and I go about printing it to the console, it first doesn't seem to exist (strangely not even throwing an error message) and when I do it again it does exist... how can this be?

Understandably providing a reproducible example here is difficult, but perhaps someone has encountered this before and could help out with ideas.

Comment: This is a known bug in `data.table`, due to something internal with how assignment is done. It's known, and it is unlikely to change. This is why you'll often see `data.table`-scripts demonstrating something arbitrarily adding `[]` to all of there data.tables. For instance, if `myDT[, newvar := 1]` prints nothing, the operation is still working and `myDT` _again_ shows that. However, if you do `myDT[, newvar := 1][]` instead, it will do the work and show it the first time. Again, known bug, I'll look for a ref for it, but ... it's the way it is.

Comment: FYI, look at the `data.table` file `NEWS` around release 1.9.6, and it cites issues [data.table#869](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/869) and [data.table#1122](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1122).

Comment: Thanks kindly for your help @r2evans, this really enlightens the issue for me!! Cheers